# Prevent Starting the launcher activity again if it is already started, just resume it

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am working on android activities. I have one main activity and two other activities, these two activities are launched from the main activity. There are back buttons on each of  When any of these two activities are launched , on pressing the back button i want the intent to start the resumed main activity, not to relaunch it on other page.
**Below is the code for Main Activity**

```js
package com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button  show_cam_ctrl,
            show_voice_ctrl;

    TextView ma_res_txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Control Buttons
        show_cam_ctrl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_cam_ctrl);
        show_voice_ctrl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_voice_ctrl);

        show_cam_ctrl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,cam_calculator.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        show_voice_ctrl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,voice_calculator.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }
```

**Codes for the two activities**

```js
public class voice_calculator extends Activity {

    Button back_frm_voice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice_calculator);

        back_frm_voice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_frm_voice);

        back_frm_voice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(voice_calculator.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
public class cam_calculator extends Activity {

Fragment cam_fragment;
Button back_frm_came;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cam_calculator);

    back_frm_came = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_frm_came);

    back_frm_came.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(cam_calculator.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
}
```

**This is the main activity, having two buttons on top BTN1 and BTN2**
[image]
**The second activity is launched on the BTN1 press, but when i press the back button on the top**
[image]
**This mainactivity is launched, but not the resumed one, when i press the back button on my phone then it get close and the main activity with calculations on screen appears, what i want is , when i press the back button, so the intent should take me to the main activity with resumed calculations.**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `cam_calculator.this.finish()` or `voice_calculator.this.finish()` from the OnClickListener. Those activities will finish and "automatically" return to the MainActivity.

**edit:**

If you put a code like this: `startActivity(new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class));` you'll directly telling the framework to start an activity.
Just remove that!

Comment: I have finished them if you look at the second code

Comment: Sorry I missed that part. So just remove the "new Intent(); startActivity()" part.

Comment: That's how Android works. When you start a new Activity it simply goes "on top" of the previous one, like a deck of cards stacked (that's why it's called the "backStack"). So if you remove the one at the top, you'll see the one bellow it.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below edited code,

```
public class voice_calculator extends Activity {

Button back_frm_voice;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice_calculator);

    back_frm_voice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_frm_voice);

    back_frm_voice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Intent i = new Intent(voice_calculator.this,MainActivity.class);
            //startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
public class cam_calculator extends Activity {

Fragment cam_fragment;
Button back_frm_came;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_cam_calculator);

back_frm_came = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_frm_came);

back_frm_came.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Intent i = new Intent(cam_calculator.this,MainActivity.class);
        //startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
});

}
}
```

The MainActivity will be in the stack, so when you do finish() in your second activity, the MainActivity will be popped and onResume() will be called instead onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're launching two children activities from a parent activity and when you press back, the parent activity is restarting. It's because the Android call stack doesn't know that the parent activity is a parent activity for the two children activities. In your Android Manifest, specify parentActivity for the two child activities like this -

```
android:parentActivityName="com.example.android.ParentActivity"
```

Let me know if it still doesn't work. Happy Coding!

Comment: Let me share some pics

Comment: Pictures have been added please check !